Find out whether filesystem supports extended attributes
I have python program that calls another (external) program:
cmd = [ "unsquashfs", "-n", "-d", dirname, filename ]
subprocess.check_call( cmd )

It worked so far. But now I started running this program in /tmp with tmpfs filesystem, which doesn't support xattrs and program subprocess fails with:
write_xattr: failed to write xattr user.random-seed-creditable for file some/file/somewhere because extended attributes are not supported by the destination filesystem
Ignoring xattrs in filesystem
To avoid this error message, specify -no-xattrs

It very kindly informed me I need to add another param, great. But the program belongs to different team, whole company uses it so I would like to minimize my change and add the param only when needed (when xattrs are not supported) - for all I know somebody somewhere depends on xattrs being set in normal case.
So, how do I implement the following?:
if not filesystemSupportsXattrs(dirname):
  cmd += ['-no-xattrs']


Are you sure the program is failing? It sounds like it's succeeding, but prints a warning that xattrs are ignored.

@thatotherguy I'm sure - program falls into pdb at check_call line with CalledProcessError

Your filesystemSupportsXattrs(dir) function can create a temporary file inside the dir and try to setfattr some attribute (say user.test-xattr-support) and check if the call succeeds or fails with ENOTSUP. Unlink the temporary file before the function returns.
